# MySQL + JSF 2 login filter

Tags: mysql, jsf-2, authentication, nullpointerexception, servlet-filters

Can someone help me with this error?
It says NullPointerException at UserDao.login and LoginBean.loginproject.
I m new to the filter in JSF 2.
Which attribute is in use from the method session.getAttribute("attribute")?

thank you by a lot

regards

UserDao.java

```
public class UserDAO {     

    ...

    public static Connection getInstance(){
        if(connection == null)
            new UserDAO();
        return connection;
    }

     public static boolean login(String user, String password) throws SQLException {
            connection = getInstance();
            String Query1 = "SELECT nama, password " + "FROM user " + "WHERE nama = ? AND password = ?";
            PreparedStatement statement1 = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(Query1);
            statement1.setString(1, user);
            statement1.setString(2, password);

            ResultSet rs = statement1.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) // found
            {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("nama"));
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
    }
}
```

LoginBean.java

```
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {

 ...
//getters setters

    public String loginProject() throws SQLException {
        boolean result = UserDAO.login(uname, password);
        if (result) {
            // get Http Session and store username
            HttpSession session = Util.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("username", uname);

            return "home";
        } else {

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                    null,
                    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN,
                    "Invalid Login!",
                    "Please Try Again!"));
            return "login";
        }
    }

    public String logout() {
      HttpSession session = Util.getSession();
      session.invalidate();
      return "login";
   }
}
```

Comment: You seem to already not understand what a `NullPointerException` is. You would otherwise have asked why variable X is `null` which would have been a much clearer question. Right now we have no clue what exactly is `null`, so we can also not explain why it is `null`. Take a step back and learn basic Java so that you understand **when** a `NullPointerException` would occur. Then, tell us which variable exactly is `null`. By the way, your DAO is leaking DB resources and is also not thread safe, which is a pretty major problem. But that's a different problem than which you asked about.

Comment: it said the nullpointer at boolean result = UserDAO.login(uname, password); from LoginBean.java and PreparedStatement statement1 = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(Query1); from UserDao.java

Comment: actually, i m trying the example from this link. the filter works, but the login doesnt.

http://knowledgeshare.awardspace.info/?p=204

Comment: So, `connection` is `null`? In other words, you haven't created the `connection`? Why not?

Comment: oh, "cannot connect". the declaration of the database name is wrong. no wonder. It works now. I still dont understand the "Attribute" thing, but it works somehow. Thx a lot. It would be nice of you if you explain it  session.setAttribute("anything") or session.getAttribute("something"). I read the doc, but cannot understand what the "anything" or "something" refers to, which attribute, where to declare them. Thx again.

Answer (score 1):

In JSF you don't need to do anything with regard to the `Session` object, unless it is explicitly needed. By putting managed beans in session scope you are lifting off the necessity of dealing with the 'raw' session object as it was in the times of Servlet+JSP combo: Faces Servlet will manage the job for you as soon as you refer to session-scoped beans in your view.

So, when you use somthing with a `session.setAttibute` flavour means that you do not want to use all the benefits JSF 2.0 provides for you out-of-the-box.

Stating this, you shall have a session-scoped bean that is holding the currently logged-in user. The login action can be moved to a request scoped bean associated with a simple view containing login form (login input field / password input field / submit login button). These two beans may look like

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class LoginUser {

    @EJB
    private UserService userService;

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{userManager}")
    private UserManager userManager;

    private String login;
    private String password;

    public LoginUser() {
    }

    public String login() {
        //checking for nulls and empty strings
        User user = userService.find(login, password);
        if(user == null) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Wrong username or password"));
            userManager.setCurrentUser(null);
            return null;
        }
        userManager.setCurrentUser(user);
        return "mypersonalspace.xhtml";
    }

}
```

and

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UserManager {

    private User currentUser;

    public UserManager() {
    }

}
```

In this setup the session will contain all the data you gave it, in our case a `User` object. You can always refer to it in your views by `#{userManager.currentUser.username}`, for example.

As a side note, you MUST always close JDBC-related elements (`ResultSet`s / `Statement`s and in the first place `Connection`s) to prevent leakage of resources. And also, take time and read literature on EJBs to use DAOs/Services appropriately.

Comment: thx for the fast respond. I am confused with an example with following code in the Filter class. if ( reqURI.indexOf("/login.jsf") >= 0 || (ses != null && ses.getAttribute("nama") != null) || reqURI.indexOf("/public/") >= 0 || reqURI.contains("javax.faces.resource") ). The ses.getAttribute("nama"), which attribute is it?

Comment: or at LoginBean.java. HttpSession session = Util.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("username", uname);  I dont know what the setAttribute refers to.

Comment: As you don't feel comfortable with web filters and Java EE in general, don't overcomplicate. Just use the standard approach. Use JSF, which is built on top of Servlet API, to avoid dealing with web servlets, sessions, etc. For authentification, your best bet is `j_security_check` or otherwise try to use a well-known security framework, like Apache Shiro, or Spring Security. For example, Shiro can initially be easily configured in an text file and will do authentification stuff for you.

Comment: And regarding the use of session object directly - don't do that. Seriously. Use `@SessionScoped` beans instead.